# iscsid broken mount after recovery

Tags: mount, iscsi, open-iscsi

I am playing with `Open-iSCSI` and came across some troubles. When the network link between my initiator and the target fails, `iscsid` will recover the connection, which is good. But my mount is broken and yields `I/O error` until it is remounted.

Is there a clean solution to remount the lun automatically? Something like a hook on post recovery or a config setting that I somehow missed? I am trying to avoid a polling script or something of the sort :)

###### iscsid log

```
Jan 14 08:03:45 localhost iscsid[1415]: iscsid: Kernel reported iSCSI connection 1:0 error (1022 - ISCSI_ERR_NOP_TIMEDOUT: A NOP has timed out) state (3)
Jan 14 08:04:22 localhost iscsid[1415]: iscsid: connect to 10.0.2.100:9999 failed (No route to host)
[...]
Jan 14 08:38:43 localhost iscsid[1415]: iscsid: connect to 10.0.2.100:9999 failed (No route to host)
Jan 14 08:38:47 localhost iscsid[1415]: iscsid: connection1:0 is operational after recovery (195 attempts)
Jan 14 08:39:52 localhost iscsid[1415]: iscsid: Kernel reported iSCSI connection 1:0 error (1020 - ISCSI_ERR_TCP_CONN_CLOSE: TCP connection closed) state (3)
Jan 14 08:40:11 localhost iscsid[1415]: iscsid: connection1:0 is operational after recovery (2 attempts)
```

###### fstab

```
UUID=cf3d20cd-a8cd-4a9a-acbf-1c61289a37bb /data xfs defaults,_netdev,x-systemd.requires=iscsid.service 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, no, there isn't a magically clean solution.  The cleanest recovery is reboot.

The problem is that when the connection is down for more than iscsid's `replacement_timeout`, the filesystem starts getting I/O errors.  Unless you have a very special application, there's typically no coming back from an I/O error.  It wreaks all sorts of havoc with services.  You're almost always better off rebooting than you are trying to sort out how all the programs stopped working.

Having said that, what you can do is push that `replacement_timeout` out as far as you're comfortable with.  You'll find references on the web to applications like databases that recommend an hour timeout (3600 seconds), or even longer.  This pushes the problem into something like a stuck NFS hard mount.  If you need to design a system that rides out outages where a human has to intervene to fix it, a much longer timeout is a good thing.  The system just hangs until the link comes back.

You can set the default for the entire system in `/etc/iscsi/iscsid.conf`.  Edit this line:

```
node.session.timeo.replacement_timeout = 120
```